# Linear process, how is $X_t$ well-defined?

Tags: linear, stochastic-processes

> **Def**. Let $ \theta \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of real-numbers such that $ \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} | \theta_j | < \infty$ and $\{W_t\}$ be a white noise with variance $\gamma$. Then a time series $\{X_t\}$ is a linear porcess if it can be represented as $$ X_t = \sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} \theta_j W_{t-j}.$$

Using the criterion for mean-square convergence, if $S = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} | \theta_j |$, then for any $ t \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$ E(X_t^2) = E(\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} \theta_j W_{t-j}) \leq \bigg(\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} | \theta_j | \sqrt{E(W_{t-j})}\bigg)^2 \stackrel{?}{=} S^2 \gamma.$$

Im failing to see why the last equality holds.

Should not $ \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} E(W_{t-j}) = \infty$ anyways, if $\gamma ≠ 0$?

Comment: The equation you displayed is obviously wrong (may be due to typo).  Probably all $E[W_{t - j}]$ is your post meant $E[W_{t - j}^2]$.

Comment: Regardless what you typed, Proposition 3..1.1 in *Time Series: Theory and Methods* by Brockwell and Davis can explain the question in your title.